# Combo Box Task Data Binding Mode : using previous combo box to set the where condition

Tags: c#, combobox, bind

I have 2 ComboBoxes. First is Region, second is Customer.

I want the second `ComboBox` to only display customers from the selected region.

So the second `ComboBox` should only have this:

> select Customer_Name from Customer WHERE customer_region = selected_region

How to do this using the GUI winform, `ComboBox` task? Can I just modify the `select` statement? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the selected region and use it in the SQL query as a parameter.  This will give you the customer names that correspond to the selected region.  Then you just add the results to the Customer ComboBox.  The following link should give you a good place to start.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/csharplanguage/thread/f3539705-a1d0-4201-a8fe-32e5b0f82e93